# Загрузить в коллекцию данные с Json

Tags: android

Есть класс образец Bluda

```
public class Bluda {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

Есть коллекция типа `List<Bluda> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();`

В папке assets есть json. Как из этого файла загрузить данные в коллекцию itemsList?

```
{
  "bluda": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Блюдо",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Блюдо",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    }
  ]
}
```

Начала делать так:

```
try {
    jsonInput = getAssets().open("json/bluda.json");
    itemsList = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(jsonInput, "UTF-8"), Bluda.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но ругается на строчку

```
itemsList = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(jsonInput, "UTF-8"), Bluda.class);
```

не знаю как правильно передать туда данные

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/5330439)

Comment: Там куча кода, я понимаю что там написано, хотелось бы короче сделать. Чувствую что можно сделать короче)

Comment: Как ругается? Какая ошибка?

Comment: ncompatible types.
Required:
java.util.List
<ru.test.mybluda.Bluda>
Found:
ru.test.mybluda.Bluda

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это вам поможет.

```
 try {
     JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("json/bluda.json"), "UTF-8"));
     itemsList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, new TypeToken<List<Bluda>>(){}.getType());
 } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Только json в данном случае должен выглядеть вот так.

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Блюдо",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Блюдо",
      "url": "ссылка",
      "image": "картинка"
    }
]
```

То есть корневой элемент - это массив. Если вам невозможно изменить структуру json-файла, то, думаю, этот пример можно модифицировать.

Comment: Поняла, а если структуру json нельзя менять?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, смотрите здесь http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Вам нужен второй класс https://pastebin.com/dPtfu7yD, получаете объект CodeResponse, в котором будет нужный список. Также всегда можно реализовать JsonDeserializer и самостоятельно указать правила для десериализации.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас у меня так и сделано. Есть второй класс, который возвращает список. Думала может быть без него как-то можно.